# I am trying to implement CDC on MySQL database using AWS DMS. Getting following errors in my dms migration task :

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MySQL.html

Referring this link to make changes in Mysql database in order to implement change data capture using AWS DMS service.

I have already tried setting paramters in my.ini file as mentioned in :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MySQL.html

```
binlog_format = ROW
expire_logs_days = 2 
binlog_checksum = NONE
binlog_row_image = FULL
log_slave_updates  = TRUE
ndb_log_bin = ON 
ndb_log_update_as_write = OFF
ndb_log_updated_only = OFF
```

Errors on AWS DMS migration task :

(Can't initialize character set unknown (path: compiled_in)) connecting to MySQL server '10.20.15.23';

Errors in MySQL server binary logging configuration.

Follow all prerequisites for 'MySQL as a source in DMS'

```
Cannot initialize subtask; Stream component 
'st_0_WBR3X727AXJYFCQBE2JX6O5AWM' terminated 
[reptask/replicationtask.c:2680][1020414] 

Stop Reason RECOVERABLE_ERROR Error Level RECOVERABLE`
```

Need solution on this. If I am not making changes correctly or if there are any additional changes required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After diving deep into the problem, I came across a solution. 
It is mandatory to set character-set values mentioned below in the 'my.ini' file 
(Windows) or 'my.cnf' file (Linux).

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake=FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

This will allow Change data capture to work efficiently without errors.